# How to get the message from process.getErrorStream()

Tags: java

```
InputStream error = p.getErrorStream();
for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {
    err += error.read();
}
System.out.println(err);
```

It gives some numeric values. But, I need to get the error message, like `e.getLocalizedMessage()` whatever it will give.

Comment: Your example is too short - what type are `p` and `err`?

Comment: `error.read();` returns `int`, what is `err` ?

Comment: Adding to a string like that (`err += whatever`) is an antipattern. Every time you add to a string, Java creates a whole new string in memory for the entire length of the string. Much better to append increments to a `StringBuilder` object and build into your string at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's InputStream.read() returns an integer value of a byte of data that is read, or (-1) if it is the end of the stream. I assume that your 'err' variable is a String, so adding an integer to a string adds the numeric value to it, therefore, you can cast error.read() to a (char) like this:

```
err += (char) error.read();
```